# Factorizing "compact" morphisms through "reflexive" objects (with respect to a given monad)

Tags: ct.category-theory

The following question arises from a hope that something true in a particular category might be true for general categorical reasons, coupled with a need to test this by looking for counterexamples.$\newcommand{\cC}{{\mathcal C}}$ I am hoping that if the question is posed in a general setting, removed from the original context, then someone who can look at it with fresh eyes will spot something that I'm not seeing.

Let $\cC$ be a category which has as all small limits and colimits and let $T$ be a monad on $\cC$ where the components of the unit, $\eta_a: a \to Ta$, are monic for each object $a$. (In the example I have in mind, $\eta_a$ is actually a regular monomorphism for each $a$.) Furthermore, although it's not needed for (1) and (2) below, let us assume that $T$ preserves and reflects monomorphisms.

Call a morphism $f:a \to b$ *$T$-compact* if $T f: Ta \to Tb$ factors through $\eta_b : b\to Tb$ (such a factorization, if it exists, is unique by monicity of $\eta_b$).Then we have a couple of easy observations:

(1) Naturality of $\eta$ shows that pre- or post-composing a $T$-compact morphism with an arbitrary morphism in $\cC$ still results in something which is $T$-compact.

(2) Let $c\in \cC$. Then the identity morphism $1_c$ is $T$-compact if and only if $\eta_c: c\to Tc$ is an isomorphism. (This uses monicity of $\eta_c$, again.) Call such an object $c$ *$T$-reflexive.*

Putting 1) and 2) together: if a morphism $f:a\to b$ factors through some $T$-reflexive object $c$, then $f$ is $T$-compact.

**Question.** Suppose $f:a\to b$ is $T$-compact. Does $f$ factor through some $T$-reflexive object $c$?

My instinct is that in general this should be far too optimistic. I do know a particular category where this works (where not every morphism is $T$-compact) but the usual construction of the factorization requires "external technology". So I am asking for counterexamples, to better understand why naive approaches to this construction (in the category where the desired result is true) are unlikely to work.

(In a certain sense the example of $\cC$ where I know things work is "not too big", and so I'd prefer counterexamples which don't rely on cardinality arguments. However I appreciate that this is a very vague comment/request.)

Comment: If $C$ has a proper factorization system and $T$ preserves it, then I think there is hope to show that $\text{Im}(f)$ is reflexive. I hope I will have time to check it tomorrow, but I might forget.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti That would be interesting. In the setting where I know this works, mono+epi need not imply iso, so dealing with Im(f) is a bit subtle, and I don't think Im(f) as a subobject of codomain(f) will be reflexive. However, the factorization that I know to exist by "outside reasons", does have something to do with Coim(f) and Im(f), so maybe your idea can be modified/adapted...

Comment: @YemonChoi Factorization systems in non-balanced categories need not lead to any problems with images. The most common case is regular epi-mono.

Comment: @KevinCarlson perhaps I was being too vague or conciliatory. In the category I have in mind, the image of a $T$-compact morphism will not in general be $T$-reflexive. I am deliberately trying not to name the category and monad in question as I want to avoid preconceptions, but it is not abelian: the canonical map from the coimage to the image is mono and epi but not iso. in general

Comment: @YemonChoi Maybe it wasn't clear that I meant "(regular epi)-mono" as opposed to "regular [as in ordinary] epi-mono?" I'm not sure what the relevance of abelianness or of the bimorphism from coimage to image would be otherwise...In any case, yes, this is probably an unhelpfully vague exercise until one gets closer to addressing your question.

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Any further thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I should be sitting with pen and paper for some time to say something relevant. :(